# Animating 2 Charetors at once (fight sene)

Tags: animation

Is it possible to animate 2 characters in the same scene at the same time? If so is there a tutorial for it?

Comment: Please give some details. If you want 2 armatures to be in Pose mode it's possible, you just need to deactivate the Lock Object Mode in the Edit menu (top menu bar)

Answer (score 0):

Animation is done with key frames, move both characters a set amount as desired, then apply a new key frame at the desired time line.  It is quite a bit of work so take your time to do it properly, as the timing is what counts a lot.  Use Ctrl+A, in object mode, and make sure you use "location,rotation, scale" every movement and keyframe you change (or appropriate /scale/rotation/location etc). Tutorials someone else might know? Hope this helps.